# App to detect Network Censorship, Surveillance etc

Tags: open-source, network-monitor

With the debate on net neutrality in full swing it seems a great idea to check if your ISP is blocking you from some sites or monitoring where you are browsing, etc.

- Ideally Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Check for Blocked sites & services
- Check for "box in the middle" for signs of traffic interception
- Possibly share the data about specific networks & ISPs

OS: Any

Answer (score 1):

### Open Observatory of Network Interference

OONIProbe Is an [Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.openobservatory.ooniprobe&hl=en_GB) or [Linux Program](https://github.com/TheTorProject/ooni-probe) that performs a number of tests to see if:

- Some web sites are blocked
- Headers are being altered in transit
- Tests for measuring the blocking of WhatsApp, Facebook Messenger, and Telegram!
- Tests for network speed shaping
- Allows sharing of results

It is Free, Gratis & Open Source.

### Warning

> Running ooniprobe might be against the terms of service of your ISP or
>   legally questionable in your country. By running ooniprobe you will
>   connect to web services which may be banned, and use web censorship
>   circumvention methods such as Tor. The OONI project will publish data
>   submitted by probes, possibly including your IP address or other
>   identifying information. In addition, your use of ooniprobe will be
>   clear to anyone who has access to your computer, and to anyone who can
>   monitor your Internet connection (such as your employer, ISP or
>   government).